# Is it defensible to offend a group of people when they cling to horrendous ideas?

Tags: ethics, metaphilosophy

Several organized or semi-organized groups of people in the world have really horrendous ideas, and react disproportionally strongly to any critique. I think most readers can agree with that statement, although we might disagree about which groups constitute examples of this. My set of such groups currently include militant Islamists like ISIS, the far right and far left political fringes in the West, the fanatically pro-Israeli (who tend to label any criticism as anti-Semitic), the fanatic Palestinians, and, yes, the typical modern day philosophers who, according to highly respected philosopher John Searle, make a living producing a lot of (quote) <sup>(1)</sup>“nonsense”.

Now my general approach to such groups is to *not accept or bow to their rules*.

[image]

E.g. I don't accept that criticism of Israel is criticism of Jews or is anti-Semitic. And e.g. I don't accept that one should discourage people from drawing caricatures of Mohammed. And in particular I don't accept that one should refrain from calling a spade a spade when it comes to nonsense philosophy . For example, I think it's right and necessary to dismiss Kurt Gödel's proof of the Christian faith's god as nonsense (it can be applied to any other incompatible god), and idiotic nonsense at that, but that doesn't mean that it would be right to say that Gödel, a mathematical genius if there ever was one, was dumb or idiotic. Geniuses can maintain idiotic things, and as I see it, I should not be so afraid of being labeled this and that that I should in any way refrain from treating the idiotic nonsense with the simple lack of respect that it does deserve, while treating the man with the enormous respect that he truly deserves (in particular for his completeness theorems, and his incompleteness theorems).

Of course, in the case of groups such as ISIS, the individual persons will probably not deserve any respect; I'm not dogmatic about respecting people.

I guess that there must be some established philosophy about this, and I guess that I would have to go in that direction in order to frame a useful question that can be simply answered, instead of as in philosophy, *discussed*.

So, tentatively I'm asking if the approach outlined about is morally defensible?

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> John Searle: “I don’t read much philosophy, it upsets me when I
read the nonsense written by my contemporaries”, in [an interview with New Philosopher Jan 25<sup>th</sup> 2014](http://www.newphilosopher.com/articles/john-searle-it-upsets-me-when-i-read-the-nonsense-written-by-my-contemporaries/).</sup>

Comment: i don't think everyone in the so called "hard left" are offensive :)

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN - Strictly speaking I don't think it's likely that _everyone_ in _any_ of those groups is "offensive", nor do I think Cheers is implying everyone is given the "probably not" rather than just "not" when applied to ISIS which is arguably the most offensive as a group from among those listed.

Comment: out of my sleeve - I suppose you can argue both ways; on the one hand calling something by its name can be useful to society, even if it hurts a particular individual or group (similarly to punishment or desert); on the other hand offending someone publicly may inflict great and unexpected distress similar to bullying; some people are liable to taking their own life in response to something they perceive as the destruction of their good name; can that be easily defended?

Comment: @nir: Re the impact on individuals, Gödel (a genius) is long gone, but following the nonsense no-M.I. idea of Gödel up through Lucas (still alive and kicking, at Cambridge I believe, publishing on the net with the help of his daughter) and then Roger Penrose, also a genius and alive & kicking, and math chair at Oxford (I think it was). Penrose's books were particularly silly and were RIDICULED, in a humoristic way, by Hans Moravec in 1995, see [http://tinyurl.com/lx7sv4j], and by me in 2010, [http://tinyurl.com/oe59blq]. My impact is like ~0, but do you think should Moravec have kept silent?

Comment: There is a difference between criticizing respectfully and offending; note that Searle does not single out a particular philosopher in the interview that you referenced; finally; according to Jewish tradition shaming your friend in public is like shedding blood - "כל המלבין פני חברו ברבים כאילו שופך דמים", where friend is taken to mean anyone else...

Comment: penrose in a box is a nice argument; you wrote that you "shamelessly reproduce his proof"; do you mean that it is penrose's argument or is it yours? I would like to note that we indeed do not know that the universe in general and that the brain in particular are computable; I think it is unfortunate that so many contemporary physicists, philosophers, and computer scientists believe that they are (apropos what Searle has said in the interview); even Feynman, the father of QED (the jewel of physics) has said that the laws of physics are just approximation of the universe.

Comment: the view that the universe is not computable is not mysticism but mysterianism; Chomsky presents that view very nicely in the following lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5in5EdjhD0 ; in second thought, I conclude that penrose in a box is your argument, since if I remember correctly, penrose believes the brain is not computable, so unless he presented that argument as a sort of _reductio ad absurdum_ then I suppose it is your argument and not his... :)

Comment: @nir: The math is Penrose's argument, but Penrose essentially copied that from Alan Turing. The idea of putting Penrose to the test instead of a machine intelligence is mine, but I am ~100% sure I was not the first: *anyone* of the critical thinking persuasion would have though of that immediately on encountering Penrose's argument (it is by no means the only fallacy). Regarding computability, that's practically impossible to know, but a brain is a small object, and there are two billion-dollar experiments going on simulating it, one by EU and one by the US (they're too optimistic, but still).

Comment: It is reasonable to believe that the _Human Brain Project_ will advance our knowledge, just as simulating the universe or a galaxy can; however, no such simulation of a galaxy can explain the inside of a supper massive blackhole at the center of the galaxy, and in analogy no simulation of a brain will explain the mind (the so called qualia); philosophers of mind and computer scientists are talking a lot about the coming singularity of AI; why don't they realize a real singularity has already happened a hundred thousand years ago - we call it a mind;

Comment: one more comment; turns out Searle does mention philosophers by names: he attacks Chalmers ruthlessly in _The Mystery of Consciousness_ "I have so far been considering only those absurdities that he explicitly commits himself to. These are bad enough, but when at one point he warns the reader that he is about to enter 'the realm of speculative metaphysics' (p. 302) (unlike the previous 300 pages?), he goes off the rails completely." [p. 157], and ironically, Chomsky who I mentioned in an earlier comment also attacks colleagues without pity.

Answer (score 3):

I see here two different questions, conflated. One is a question about the **right** to speak in a certain way, given some circunstances. The other is a question about of the virtuousness of a specific line of **action**, given those same circumstances. The first one is about *free speech*, the second, about *moral duty*.

I'd say, preventively, that freedom of speech is something that applies to silence also. You should be free to *not manifest* about something. It is typical of fascist regimes to capture free speech by first capturing free silence. That's an old trap, and we must always be vigilant to avoid falling in it.

To answer your question more directly: your definition of "horrendous" is casuistic (and that does **not** mean I disagree, neither that I agree with it). For some *concrete* line of action to be defensible (ethically), it is enough that it can be aptly defended. That some concrete attitude is "defensible" doesn't take away one iota of responsability from the agent. Also, the ethics of concrete action ("is it right to do x?") is normally the subject of law scholars or ideologues, not philosophers.

Additionally, I'd say that there can be efficacy in not acting, as there can be in acting. Political action is, first of all, strategy. Tactics comes in a distant second place.